# Convergence of the sequence $ x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}+....+x_{n-p}}p $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For arbitrary real number $x_0, x_1, ....,x_{p-1}$, define $x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}+....+x_{n-p}}p $  ($n\geq p $)

If $x_n$ converges, then the limit is equal to $$\frac {2X}{p(p+1)}\quad \text{while}\quad X=px_{p-1}+(p-1)x_{p-2}+...+x_0$$
For example, In the case of $p=3$, one can show that $3x_n+2x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$ is constant. Adding $\frac 23x_{n-1}+\frac 13x_{n-2}$ on both sides of

$$x_n=\frac13x_{n-1}+\frac13x_{n-2}+\frac13x_{n-3}$$, we get

$$x_n+\frac 23x_{n-1}+\frac 13x_{n-2}=x_{n-1}+\frac23 x_{n-2}+\frac 13x_{n-3}$$

So all I have to do is show that $x_n$ is convergent. 
But how?? I'm completely stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method: Clearly
$$
\{x_n\mid n\geq N\}\subseteq[\min\{x_N,\dots,x_{N+p-1}\},\max\{x_N,\dots,x_{N+p-1}\}]
$$
for all $N$.  Let
$$
d_n=\max\{x_n,\dots,x_{n+p-1}\}-\min\{x_n,\dots,x_{n+p-1}\}
$$
and show that there is an $r<1$ such that $d_{n+p}\leq r d_n$